# Bug in SQLAlchemy Rollback after DB Exception?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, rollback

My SQLAlchemy application (running on top of MariaDB) includes two models `MyModelA` and `MyModelB` where the latter is a child-record of the former:

```
class MyModelA(db.Model):
    a_id   = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    my_field1 = db.Column(db.String(1024), nullable=True)

class MyModelB(db.Model):
    b_id   = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    a_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(MyModelA.a_id), nullable=False)
    my_field2 = db.Column(db.String(1024), nullable=True)
```

These are the instances of `MyModelA` and `MyModelB` that I create:

```
>>> my_a = MyModelA(my_field1="A1")
>>> my_a.aid
1
>>> MyModelB(a_id=my_a.aid, my_field2="B1")
```

I have the following code that deletes the instance of `MyModelA` where `a_id==1`:

```
db.session.commit()
try:
    my_a = MyModelA.query.get(a_id=1)
    assert my_a is not None
    print "#1) Number of MyModelAs: %s\n" % MyModelA.query.count()
    db.session.delete(my_a)
    db.session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
    print "#2) Cannot delete instance of MyModelA because it has child record(s)!"
    db.session.rollback()
    print "#3) Number of MyModelAs: %s\n" % MyModelA.query.count()
```

When I run this code look at the unexpected results I get:

```
#1) Number of MyModelAs: 1
#2) Cannot delete instance of MyModelA because it has child record(s)!
#3) Number of MyModelAs: 0
```

The delete supposedly fails and the DB throws an exception which causes a rollback. However even after the rollback, the number of rows in the table indicates that the row -- which supposedly wasn't deleted -- is actually gone!!!

Why is this happening? How can I fix this? It seems like a bug in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: have you checked if autocommit is disabled ?

Comment: same idea: you say that you use MariaDB. Which kind of engine in MariaDB ? MyISAM does not support transactions, so it is always in "autocommit" mode

Comment: What are the queries generated by sqlalchemy?  Do the `SELECTs` have `FOR UPDATE`?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
Your problem might be related to the lack of explicit relationship declaration.

For example, [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship) there is a sample of objects' relationship. In addition to the usage of a ForeignKey field, the class explicitly uses the `relationship` directive to define that connection. In the [session API documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html), the following text appears:

> object references should be constructed at the object level, not at the foreign key level

Which might imply to the way of SQLAlchemy to manage relations. I am not deeply familiar with the underlying mechanisms, but it is possible that this is what happens. Your session only includes the `MyModelA` object. Since you did not use the `relationship()` directive in the definition of `MyModelB`, objects of `MyModelA` type are not aware to the fact that some other object might refer them through a `ForeignKey`. Hence, when the session is about to commit, it is not aware to the fact that deleting the object affects some other `MyModelB` object, and its transaction mechanism does not take that into account. 
I suggest that adding the relationship explicitly might prevent that behavior.